# How to know if a coordinate is within a polygon in shapefile not working?

Tags: python, shapely

I have

- coordinates (lat and lng) in an Excel document
- a shapefile which contains all the different Canada provinces shapes.

I would like to be able to generate a new field in Excel in order to classify the different coordinates into the different canada provinces, census division and sub division

I tried the below code, but it is not working.

```
import fiona
import shapely.geometry 

with fiona.open(r"D:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\CRA-Project v2\Census Division\lcd_000b16a_e.shp") as fiona_collection:

shapefile_record = fiona_collection.next()

# Use Shapely to create the polygon
shape = shapely.geometry.asShape(shapefile_record['geometry'])
#print(shape)

point = shapely.geometry.Point(46.362914,-63.503809) # longitude, latitude

# Alternative: if point.within(shape)
if shape.contains(point):
    print("Found shape for point.")
```

**Update 1:**

```
point = shapely.geometry.Point(46.362914,-63.503809)
```

Polygon:
[Link](https://docdro.id/lnaq5aT)

**Update 2:**

```
import fiona
import shapely.geometry 

with fiona.open(r"D:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\CRA-Project v2\Census Division\lcd_000b16a_e.shp") as fiona_collection:

shapefile_record = next(iter(fiona_collection))

shape = shapely.geometry.asShape(shapefile_record['geometry'])
#print(shape)

point = shapely.geometry.Point(573339.364,6177352.077)

if shape.intersects(point):
    print("Found shape for point.")
```

UTM:

```
point = shapely.geometry.Point(573339.364,6177352.077)
```

New Polygon: [Here](https://www.docdroid.net/96tBkLd/newpolygon.txt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it appears you're using Eastings/Northings rather than longitude/latitude. It might help to see a screenshot of your excel file to ensure the points are in the same coordinate system as the polygon.

Secondly, your point has one of the same vertices as the polygon.  That means, that the `contains` method will return a false. Contains should be used if the point is fully within the polygon, your point is on the boundary of the polygon.

However, if you change `contains` to `intersects` you'll get a true result if you want to ensure points on the edge of the polygon are counted.

I used JTS Topology Suite Testbuilder to test some geometries and different predicates.

I created a rectangle as per the following WKT:

```
POLYGON ((200 600, 600 600, 600 300, 200 300, 200 600))
```

And a point with coordinates on one of the vertices:

```
POINT (200 600)
```

You can see the point in the top left corner below:
[image]

When I run the different predicate tests you can see that "touches" and "intersects" give the results you want.

[image]

*Apologies for the resolution of the images.*

---

Two comments based on your edits.

1. Your point coordinates will need to be converted to eastings/northings instead of lat/long. Shapely won't intersect them otherwise.
2. The polygon geometry you've linked to is either not complete or it is corrupt. It appears that it gets cut off and is not displaying the mantissa (fractional part) of the coordinate of a vertex. Also, there are no closing brackets. Notice there are three opening brackets at the beginning. There should be three closing brackets to match. When I try to load this geometry into JTS Topology Suite, I get the following error: "*Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring.*"

EDIT 2:

Now that you've fixed the polygon and converted the coordinates of the point, now it seems that the point and polygon are disjoint and do not overlap.

[image]

Comment: I have inserted a real coordinate, but even that it doesn't recognize it. I have inserted the whole polygon result. Do you have an idea why it isn't ?

Comment: See my edits at the end of my post to respond to your edits/comments.

Comment: I have checked the 2 comments and I have posted a new update on my post. I have tried to convert a lat/lng to UTM 14U. and took a smaller polygon. I am still not getting it. Am I missing anything from the code part ?

Comment: @Jonathan, I've added a screenshot showing that your point and polygon do not intersect.

Comment: I have downloaded the JTS app you mentioned above. I have ran it and saw the result you posted on edit 2. This is first time dealing with UTM, Are there different kinds of them ? So I should get the point inside the polygon to be sure that the UTM is correct ? Is there any tools you recommend to use to convert lat and lng to UTM ?

Comment: I suggest you research projected co-ordinate systems for your region. It may not be a UTM projection. Then please ask a new question rather than ask in the comments.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, If you have an idea on this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304492/how-to-convert-latitude-and-longitude-to-lambert-conformal-conic-projection